# Plot missing legend when multiple plotting

Tags: r

I am trying to make multiple plots of my data whilst colour coding them based on a `grouping`. I want to include legends on each plot that go outside the scope of the `box`. This works however, my first plot has no legend but the rest of my plots do.

For example:

```
library(faraway)
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
data(savings)

group_data <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  savings %>% mutate(test = ifelse(.[, y] > x, "Group 1 (GT)", "Group 2 (LT)"))
}, val, names(val), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
  mapply(function(a,z) {
    a %>% `colnames<-`(c(names(.)[-length(.)], glue("{z}_group")))
  }, ., names(.), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>% 
  Reduce(cbind, .) %>% 
  .[, !duplicated(names(.))] 

nn <- length(val)
ng <- names(group_data)[(length(group_data)-nn+1):length(group_data)]
n2 <- n2mfrow(nn, 2)
par(mfrow=n2, xpd=TRUE)

mapply(function(q, w){
  form <- reformulate(q, response='sr')
plot(form, data=group_data, col=c('red', 'blue')[as.factor(group_data[,w])], pch=c(19, 19))

legend( x=0, 26,
        legend=c("Group 1 (GT)","Group 2 (LT)"),
        col=c("red","blue"), lwd=1, lty=c(0,0), 
        pch=c(19,19), bty='n' )
  
},names(val),ng, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Plots the following:
[image]

The data `val`:

```
list(pop15 = 35, pop75 = 2.5, dpi = 2000, ddpi = 7)
```

With response to the comments by @Harre, the following manipulates `x` for the missing legend:

```
if(q == 'pop15'){
legend( x=21, 26,
        legend=c("Group 1 (GT)","Group 2 (GT)"),
        col=c("red","blue"), lwd=1, lty=c(0,0), 
        pch=c(19,19), bty='n' )} else{
          legend( x=0, 26,
                  legend=c("Group 1 (GT)","Group 2 (LT)"),
                  col=c("red","blue"), lwd=1, lty=c(0,0), 
                  pch=c(19,19), bty='n' )
        }
```

And I see all 4 legends now.

Unfortunately, If I add more columns likeso:

```
savings$status <- savings$pop15+1
val <- c(val, status=list(37))
```

Then repeat the code I get the following:
[image]

With @Harre's answer I got led to the right solution:

```
group_data <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  savings %>% mutate(group = ifelse(.[, y] > x, "Group 1 (GT)", "Group 2 (LT)"))
}, val, names(val), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
  mapply(function(a,z) {
    a %>% `colnames<-`(c(names(.)[-length(.)], glue("{z}_group")))
  }, ., names(.), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>% 
  Reduce(cbind, .) %>% 
  .[, !duplicated(names(.))] %>% pivot_longer(-c(1:(length(.)-nn))) %>% dplyr::select(group=value) %>% cbind.data.frame(savings %>% pivot_longer(-c(1)), .)

val_hline <- val %>% unlist() %>% data.frame(hline=.) %>% rownames_to_column() %>% `colnames<-`(c('name', 'hline'))

kop <- inner_join(group_data, val_hline, by='name')

kop %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, y = sr, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(name ~ ., scales = "free") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
        legend.position = "bottom") + 
  stat_smooth(method='lm') +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=hline))
```

[image]

Comment: I can see all four legends: Your problem is that pop15 isn't starting a x=0. That being said, I'll want to check out if you could control legend placement in a more robust way.

Comment: Suggestion: Check out `ggplot`'s `facet_wrap()` and go with one single legend.

Comment: @harre I doubt that you see all 4 if I see all 3 and we use the same code. thank you for the suggestion however I am avoiding ggplot because it does not plot as easily compared to base plot within my functons

Comment: Alternatively, with regards to what you said: -"That being said, I'll want to check out if you could control legend placement in a more robust way." this has led me to the solution! thnak you. However, not sure how practical this is if I have a dataset with multiple columns

Comment: I do indeed see all four :-) Happy it led you to the solution.

Comment: @harre it turns out that all four legends shows when I squish the plot margins on my IDE. It does not seem that I can effectively plot that static outside the margins so I will look into your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggested `ggplot`-solution, in the case you want to explore:

```r
savings |>
    pivot_longer(-sr) |>
    # I have collected your val's here for illustration; feel free to use the lists
    mutate(group = case_when(name == "pop15" & value > 35 ~ "Group 1 (GT)",
                             name == "pop75" & value > 2.5 ~ "Group 1 (GT)",
                             name == "dpi" & value > 2000 ~ "Group 1 (GT)",
                             name == "ddpi" & value > 7 ~ "Group 1 (GT)",
                             TRUE ~ "Group 2 (GT)")) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = sr, color = group)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(name ~ ., scales = "free") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]